# How to return value with callback function and regular func

Tags: angular6

I want to get object companies from localStorage if exist and
 return it
     and go to server and update companies in localStorage

if localStorageCompanies is empty i need to subscribe the one who
 called the 
      function to get the result from the server, hot i do it?

and how i exeute this code:

```
localStorage.setItem('companies',JSON.stringify(res.result));
```

After this code:

```
if(!localStorageCompanies){
    return res;
}




getCompanies(): any {
     const localStorageCompanies =  localStorage.getItem('companies');

      this.http.get(environment.apiUmbracoUrl+'home/GetCompanies').subscribe(
       res => {
         //this.sharedService.turnOnLoader();
         if(res.rc == 0){      
           localStorage.setItem('companies',JSON.stringify(res.result));
           if(!localStorageCompanies){
             return res;
           }
        } 
       });


    if(localStorageCompanies){
      return {rc:1,result:JSON.stringify(localStorageCompanies)};
    }
 }
```